# Updating ESRI Rest services with post

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, esri

I am atempting to post a new url to a service on ESRI (I own it) with a post using `Requests`.  After printing the line `post_url` the JSON is updated as I want it however when I post it nothing happens despite getting a `200` status. Is the issue with the `post` or the `find / replace`?

```
json_url = "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/serviceID?&token=XXX"
update_url = "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/users/USERNAME/folder/items/ServiceNumber/update?"

get_json = requests.get(json_url)
load_json = str(get_json.json())


find = "findme"
replace = "replace"

post_url = load_json.replace(replace, find)


a = requests.post(update_url, data={"url": post_url, "token": "XXXX", "f":"json"})
print a.status_code
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with the post request. Either it is expecting some more headers or cookies. Try printing `a.content`

Comment: this error is generated: `{"error":{"code":500,"message":"DBUtil.doUpdateTransaction(): failed, ","details":["DBUtil.doUpdateTransaction(): failed, "]}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the post

I changed the `post` to this:
`requests.request("POST", update_url, data={"url": post_url, "token": token, "f":"json"})`

`update_url` needs to be the API update endpoint:
`https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/users/USERNAME/FOLDER/items/Endpoint /update?"`

`post_url` needs to be: "whatever you want" in my case It was a search and replace variable of the the existing URL in the JSON and update, because of a server migration.