# Proper/Pythonic use of requests and the return of a response method

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I have found two methods of making a "post" documented on the [requests site](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

1: `requests.request(method, url, **kwargs)` source: http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Request

2:  `r = requests.post(url, data={"url": post_url, "token": token, "f":"json"})` source:http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

I had an issue where I could only get the first method to work which is posted on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876220/updating-esri-rest-services-with-post).  Why is this the case? And what are the differences between the two.

I did not have to use `requests.request("GET", url, **kwargs)` because  `requests.get(url)` worked which I found not to be true for `post`

Comment: That's a matter of opinion. `request.post()` is there for convenience, and I don't see reasons not to use it, unless you're writing some generic code that calculates the method dynamically or accepts it from the outside.

Comment: I don't think it is a matter of opinion because one worked and the other did not...What details would help the discussion (there is a link to a SO thread that has the problem)

Comment: What's your `kwargs`? Does `requests.request('POST', url, **kwargs)` work differently than `requests.post(url, **kwargs)`?

Comment: please look at the referenced post to see the `kwargs`...Yes `requests.request` makes the `post` while `requests.post` gives a `200` status but an error, the error can be seen in the referenced post.

Comment: In the referenced post you're sending the data form-encoded, and here you're sending json. Which is relevant?

Comment: don't follow? Could be the problem

Comment: `requests.post(url, data={'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'})` and `requests.post(url, data=json.dumps({'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}))` do [different things](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v1.0.1/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests). The first sends form-encoded `a=b&c=d`, the second one sends `{"a": "b", "c": "d"}`.

Comment: good catch...I did not try the dumps in the workflow I got to work..Ill edit OP